# Repeating elements when appending in iteration in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to code a portion of code that gets the elements from two distinct lists and make a match, as you can see below, but for some reason, I keep getting repeated elements on my output lists.

```
def assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time):
    """Assign operators to pending requests.

    Requires:
    - operators, a collection of operators, structured as the output of 
      filesReading.read_operators_file;
    - requests, a list of requests, structured as the output of filesReading.read_requests_file;
    - current_time, str with the HH:MM representation of the time for this update step.
    Ensures: a list of assignments of operators to requests, according to the conditions indicated 
    in the general specification (omitted here for the sake of readability).
    """
    operators = sorted(operators, key=itemgetter(3, 4, 0), reverse=False)
    requests = sorted(requests, key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
    isAssigned = 0
    tasks = []
    langr = 0 #Variable that gets the language of the request's file (customer's language)
    lango = 0 #Variable that gets the language of the operator's file (operator's language)
    for i in range(len(requests)-1):
        langr = requests[i][1]                                   #What language does the customer speaks?
        for k in range(len(operators)-1):
            lango = operators[k][1]                              #What language does the operator speaks?
            if langr == lango:                                   #Do they speak the same language?
                for j in range(len(operators[k][2])-1):
                    if (operators[k][2][j] == requests[i][2]) and (operators[k][4] <= 240):     # The operator knows how to solve the client's problem? If yes, then group them together.
                        a = operators[k][2][j]
                        b = requests[i][2]
                        tasks.append([current_time, requests[i][0], operators[k][0]])
                        operator_time = operators[k][4]
                        request_time = requests[i][4]
                        new_operator_time = operator_time + request_time
                        operators[k][4] = new_operator_time
                        isAssigned == True
                        #operators.remove(operators[k])
                        requests.remove(requests[i])
                    else:
                        isAssigned = False
                    if isAssigned == False:
                        tasks.append([current_time, requests[i][0], "not-assigned"])

        operators = sorted(operators, key=itemgetter(3, 4, 0), reverse=False)

    return tasks, operators, requests
```

My current input is this:

```
operators = [['Atilio Moreno', 'portuguese', ('laptops',), '10:58', 104], ['Leticia Ferreira', 'portuguese', ('laptops',), '11:03', 15], ['Ruth Falk', 'german', ('phones', 'hifi'), '11:06', 150], ['Marianne Thibault', 'french', ('phones',), '11:09', 230], ['Mariana Santana', 'portuguese', ('phones',), '11:11', 230], ['Beate Adenauer', 'german', ('hifi', 'phones'), '11:12', 140], ['Zdenka Sedlak', 'czech', ('phones',), '11:13', 56], ['Romana Cerveny', 'czech', ('phones',), '11:13', 213]]
requests = [['Christina Holtzer', 'german', 'hifi', 'fremium', 7], ['Andrej Hlavac', 'czech', 'phones', 'fremium', 9], ['Dulce Chaves', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 15], ['Otavio Santiago', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 15], ['Dina Silveira', 'portuguese', 'phones', 'fremium', 9], ['Rafael Kaluza', 'slovenian', 'laptops', 'fremium', 13], ['Sabina Rosario', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 10], ['Nuno Rodrigues', 'portuguese', 'laptops', 'fremium', 12], ['Feliciano Santos', 'portuguese', 'phones', 'fremium', 12]]

current_time = "14:55 06:11:2017"
print(assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time))
```

My current output is three lists where, for example, the first one is something like this:

```
[[11:05, Christina Holtzer, not-assigned],[11:05, Christina Holtzer, Beate Adenauer],[11:05, Andrej Hlavac, not-assigned]]
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly. Please fix.

Comment: What is the actual input? It's hard to figure out why you get that if I don't know what you put in.

Comment: What exactly is incorrect about your output? Can you be more explicit? realize, we do not have any context about what you are trying to do...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It gives me the same request two times. As you can see from the output, there are two "Christina Holtzer" requests.

Comment: Well, for starters, you are modifying `requests` while iterating over it: `requests.remove(requests[i])`. Furthermore, `requests.remove(requests[i])` always removes the *first* instance it encounters, so there's a lot of potential bugs. It's hard to say exactly what is going wrong without a [mcve]

Comment: Also, why are you looping over `for i in range(len(requests)-1)`? Why not `for req in requests:`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hi! I have added the input info. Where exactly it is not idented properly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was thinking in iterating on the list positions (0, 1, 2...) that's why! But I guess your command would work fine too.

Comment: @MiguelSantana well, that is usually an anit-pattern unless you are using the indices to do something other than index into the list at that exact index. Did you mean to skip the last element in your lists?

Comment: I dont want to be rude, but this code is almost unreadable, looks like C. You should use some type of encapsulation for your operators and requests, even a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) will do. (Almost)

Comment: @JoseA. a `namedtuple` would do wonders for readability here...

Comment: Also, I upvoted because you have responded promptly to requests for clarification/example data.

Comment: Although, again I ask, did you *mean* to skip the last elements in your lists on ever loop? i.e. the effect of doing `for i in range(len(x) - 1)` will iterate over all but the *last* index in some list `x`... But I think you are getting repetition because you are looping over the *product* of your two lists, where I think you want every distinct pair instead...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I dont know if you are being sarcastic, but I actually mean it. Not C-Style for loops, namedtuple... and the readability will improve by a factor of over 9000. IMO.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No I do not, but I was thinking that the range() gives an integer number of the length and when iterating, we always want to do 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1 for the list positions, otherwise it will give me the "out of range" error.

Comment: The answer to what you asked is because of bad logic. You decide isAssigned immediately on the first language match, again for each language match, regardless of other criteria. You could also greatly improve readability by using python for loops and the "in" operator, and good variable names. If it's complicated, re-write it with good function names hiding complicated details, then work on those functions.

Comment: @MiguelSantana no, the `range` stop parameter is non-inclusive. So it works well with `for i in range(len(mylist))`. But you should be looping that way in this case anyway, use `for item in mylist:`. Also, I think your repetition is occurring because you are looping over the cartesian product, rather than over distinct pairs... But yeah, so aside from that error in logic, you have the bug that you are ignoring the last elements in all your lists, *and* you are `.remove`ing from a list while iterating over it, which will cause you to skip items...

Comment: @KennyOstrom Hi Kenny! Thanks for your answer. I will see what I can do for the code improvement. How can I fix the isAssigned part?

Comment: write a function can_handle(operator, request) -> boolean. Have it check language and qualifications. That should simplify the code which uses it enough so you can see where to set isAssigned. (assuming you keep the double for loop, which is not efficient)

Comment: @MiguelSantana. The contents of your function is not indented past your `def`.

Comment: @MiguelSantana. I've gone ahead and fixed that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I dont really know the logic you are after, that is not even my point, my point is that probably you can't focus on the logic because you are too busy with those index thing. So I have taken the liberty to modify your code a little bit to show what is important, and if you are using python, you should take advantage of this feature, because readability counts.

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, lan):
        self.name = name
        self.lan = lan

    def is_compatible(self, other):
        if other.lan == self.lan:
            return True
        return False

class Requester(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, problem, mode, time, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.problem = problem
        self.mode = mode
        self.time = time

class Operator(Person):
    def __init__(self, *args, expertise, hour, time, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.expertise = expertise
        self.hour = hour
        self.time = time
        self.assigned = False

operators = [
    Operator(name='Atilio Moreno', lan='portuguese', expertise=('laptops',), hour='10:58', time=104),
          .
          .
          .
    Operator(name='Romana Cerveny', lan='czech',  expertise=('phones',), hour='11:13', time=213),
]

requests = [
    Requester(name='Christina Holtzer', lan='german', problem='hifi', mode='fremium', time=7),
          .
          .
          .
    Requester(name='Feliciano Santos', lan='portuguese',  problem='phones',  mode='fremium', time=12),
]
```

With this done, the task of thinking about the logic becomes much simpler, just type what you are thinking:

```
def assign_tasks(operators, requests, current_time):
    operators.sort(key=attrgetter('hour', 'time', 'name'))
    requests.sort(key=attrgetter('mode'))
    tasks = []
    for requester in requests:
        for operator in operators:
            if requester.is_compatible(operator) and requester.problem in operator.expertise and operator.time < 240:
                if not operator.assigned:
                    tasks.append([current_time, requester.name, operator.name])
                    operator.assigned = True
                    operator.time += requester.time
                    break # Breaks out of second for-loop so we go to the next requester
        else: #In case no operator is available
            tasks.append([current_time, requester.name, 'not-assigned'])
    return tasks, operators, requests

tasks, operators, requests = assign_tasks(operators=operators, requests=requests, current_time=0)

print(tasks)
```

The output of this is:

```
 [[0, 'Christina Holtzer', 'Ruth Falk'], [0, 'Andrej Hlavac', 'Zdenka Sedlak'], [0, 'Dulce Chaves', 'Atilio Moreno'], [0, 'Otavio Santiago', 'not-assigned'], [0, 'Dina Silveira', 'not-assigned'], [0, 'Rafael Kaluza', 'not-assigned'], [0, 'Sabina Rosario', 'not-assigned'], [0, 'Nuno Rodrigues', 'not-assigned'], [0, 'Feliciano Santos', 'not-assigned']]
```

That's kinda long, but there are all the requester either they have an operator or not.

Again, **I dont know if this logic is the logic you are after** but I hope you see that with this approach it is simpler to think about the problem (what really matters) and it is also simpler for others to read.

Comment: That's so kind of you! Thank you very much! But I am afraid I can't do that, since this is a college project and I haven't learned yet the "class" mechanism. And yes, that is the logic I am going after! ;)

Comment: @MiguelSantana You can almost do the same with just a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) the only lines you will have trouble with are `operator.time += requester.time`  and `assigned = False` because tuples are immutable.

Comment: @JoseA. You could just use dicts with keys like `'time'` and `'assigned'`. That's basically what a simple class does for you anyway.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Very true. Is just a personal preference, I dont like all those brackets. And this is more general.

Comment: @Jose of course I much prefer your solution. I just meant for OP's restriction on using classes.